# Shortcut connections (from Deep Residual Learning)

Tags: deep-learning

In the paper "Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition" the authors make use of, so called, shortcut connections. How do they work and where could I find more information about them?

Comment: These are links passing the same information ('identity' means that this information is not altered).

Comment: Check out this comment here about skip layer connections in the recent MSR article: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/neural-network-with-skip-layer-connections/189534#189534